# How can I set Powershell ExecutionPolicy in C# form?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have tried the following methods yet nothing seems to get it. The registry entry does not get set. The code does not throw an error, and it is executed as an admin.

First the easy way

```
localKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell", true);
localKey.SetValue("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted", RegistryValueKind.String);

localKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell", true);
localKey.SetValue("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Then using the system automation from NuGet

```
            using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PS.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
                PS.AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "unrestricted");
                PS.Invoke();
            }
```

All this is to execute a powershell script:

```
ps.AddScript(ps1_GenComNam + @"\GenerateComputerName.ps1").Invoke();
```

Is there a way to execute the PS script using an execution policy of unrestricted?

Comment: The "easy way" is extremely user-hostile (why the hell would you modify policy for my entire platform?!), calling `Set-ExecutionPolicy` explicitly is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PS.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicty unrestricted;");
                PS.Invoke();
            }
```

Could you try that and tell me if that works for you ? I can't test it out for now, not on the good PC :D

Edit :

So, i got on my computer, and, it work for me (All NuGet at v7.0.0)

When i run this :

```
using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PS.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; Get-ExecutionPolicy");
                Collection<PSObject> results = PS.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
                }
            }
```

It return Unrestricted, i can try with different execution policy, the result is the same, my process got the execution level i need.

Running this variation (Restricted for all Scope when i execute it) :

```
using (PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PS.AddScript("Get-ExecutionPolicy; Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; Get-ExecutionPolicy");
                Collection<PSObject> results = PS.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
                }
            }
```

I got

```
Restricted
Unrestricted

Sortie de .\ConsoleApp1.exe (processus 13532). Code : 0.
```

The -Scope Process make it returning to normal after executing it, but i can execute my process effectively.

I don't know what is going bad for you sadly.

Comment: I tried that and does not seem to be doing anything. a -list still pulls up Undefined for all.

Comment: Ok, just made some test, edited my answer

Comment: so you are running that in a console app. Mine is a form. When I run it in a console app I get the same results as you. Not sure what's going on, but I will try to translate it to a windows form app and see if can get the same result.

Comment: That seems to have worked in my test app but only under the scope process. It doesn't work if I use -scope LocalMachine. Not the end of the world, I just have to modify my code and test it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm not sure you can edit other than the process scope, that would mean that all apps that you install could potentially edit you execution policy without warning you about it, and I think this is a huge security issue. I'm not sure about it, but that could be the expected behaviour.

Comment: So.... Turns out it was a PICNIC error - I had the solution compiled for Any Computer. Once I set it to X64 it worked just fine. Thank you all for the help - I actually learned something from this!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was a PICNIC error. I compiled the code for 32-bit and not 64-bit. It was setting it for 32-bit PowerShell. Once I compiled it for 64-bit it worked fine.

Thank you all.